# How to compare a password with a hashed one in database when sign-up(pass hashing) and login are in 2 different javascript function?

Tags: javascript, authentication, hash, bcrypt

I am working on an authentication program in javascript. I have it working without the hashing. To do so, I use a database where I store the userID, username and password. the user info is added to the database using a sign-up function. Then we have a login page that sends a sql query to get the user using username and password. If there is a match then we set the session to the user found and we go to the dashboard.

When using hashing, I hash the the password successfully using **bcrypt** and i store it in the database. However, When trying to compare a password given by user using the **compare function** of bcrypt, the hash is not defined. How can I make it work?

I have tried to use the following:

> let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);

This hashed the password given by the user but this will give me a new different password since this is how hashing works. When not including the hash variable, I always get the error that it is not defined.

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
  let sess = req.session;
  if(req.method === "POST"){        
    let bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    let saltRounds = 10;
    let post = req.body;
    let name = post.user_name;
    let password = post.password;
    let sql = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name, user_name FROM `users` WHERE `user_name`='" + name + "'";

    bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, res) {
        db.query(sql, function(err, results){
         if(results.length && res){
            req.session.userId = results[0].id;
            req.session.user = results[0];
            console.log(results[0].id);
            res.redirect('/home/dashboard');
         }
         else{
            message = 'Username or password incorrect';
            res.render('index.ejs',{message: message});
         }

      });
    });
  } else {stuff}
}
```

The password hashing is done like so in another function:

```
exports.signup = function(req, res){
message = '';
if(req.method === "POST"){
   // bcrypt hashing: Maybe planning on doing passport if usefull
   let bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
   let saltRounds = 10;
   let post = req.body;
   let name = post.user_name;
   let password = post.password;
    bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
             let sql = "INSERT INTO `users`(`user_name`,`password`) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + hash + "')";
             let query = db.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                 message = "Account has been created.";
                 res.render('signup.ejs', {message: message});
             });
    });


} else {
  res.render('signup');
}
};
```

The aim would be to have a hashed password with a working comparison. Right now, I only have the hashing working and I have no clue on how to do the second part.

> I would like to keep the 2 functions separated

The code is working without the hashing. But an upgrade is the aim.

Comment: You need to query the DB first to get the password hash, then you can use `compare` on that with the password from the request.

Comment: The alternative would be to use `bcrypt.hash` like in the signup code, then check whether the username and password hash match the database (in the same way you did it without hashing) - the only problem with that is that the comparison might not be constant-time, allowing a certain class of attacks.

Comment: I will try both. You should post this as an answer so that if it works I can check your answer and mark it as resolved! Thanks!

Comment: Edit: The first solution doesn't work, I still get the hash is not defined error. The second solution might not be understood properly but hashing the password given by the user when logging in and comparing it with the one in the database will fail.

Comment: Ah, the `bcrypt.hash` call might create a new salt - of course it doesn't work then.

Comment: @Bergi yes this is exactly what is happening according to the console.logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then we have a login page that sends a sql query to get the user using username and password. If there is a match then we set the session to the user found and we go to the dashboard.

The same approach should be used now. Instead of retrieving the password, you retrieve the hash, and instead of checking it for equality you use `bcrypt.compare`.

> However, when trying to compare a password given by user using the compare function of bcrypt, the hash is not defined. How can I make it work?

Your `hash` variable is not defined because you need to do the SQL query first:

```
let name = post.user_name;
let password = post.password;
// TODO: rename "password" column to "password_hash"
let sql = "SELECT id, password, first_name, last_name, user_name FROM `users` WHERE `user_name`=?";
//                    ^^^^^^^^               prevent SQL injection by using parameterised query ^

db.query(sql, name, function(err, results) {
  if(!err && results.length) {
    var hash = results[0].password;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, ok) {
      if (!err && ok) {
        req.session.userId = results[0].id;
        req.session.user = results[0];
        …
      } else{
        …
      }
    });
  } else {
    …
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, the question mark would be part of the string. However I don't know what `db` is, what library you are using, or how the syntax should look like exactly - it was just a guess of mine how it might look, and to highlight that you need to do something. Check the documentation of your database library for how to use it correctly.

Comment: ok, your solution is pretty close to what I was doing to fix this. The only difference is the SQL injection prevent. It throws an error with the ? in the string so i will try to fix it asap.

Comment: Okay right now, with or without the injection prevent, My page keeps loading, debugging shows that the program stops at the if(result.length) statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "stops"? Does it throw an exception? Is there any error message? Regardless, this has nothing to do with the login procedure specifically: make sure you are using the database correctly.

Comment: This worked. The answer was detailed and helped me understand what was happening. Thank you.